# В дебаг панели yii2 отображается дубликат страницы, а не отладочная информация

Tags: yii2

Свежеустановленная через композер yii2 advanced. Ничего ещё не ставилось. Первый модуль, который запускаю - дебаг-модуль. При этом панель отображается, проблем нет, но по клику на неё, отображается не отладочная инфорамация, а дублируется открытая страница, как на скриншоте. При этом у новой продублированной страницы есть своя дебаг-панель, на которую тоже можно кликнуть и потом открывается новый клон этой де страницы и так до бесконечности. По клику на ссылку `/view?panel=asset&tag=65874dce59118` в новом окне открывается собственно сама страница, а не отладочная информация.

Обнаружил зависимость этой проблемы от следующего участка кода в файле `frontend/confing/main.php`

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
    ],
],
```

Ошибка проявляется только тогда, когда `'enablePrettyUrl' => true,` если `'enablePrettyUrl' => false`, то всё ок.

На скриншоте видно окно браузера, которое разделилось пополам после клика на дебаг-панель. Вверху - страница, а внизу вместо отладочной информации находится визуальный дубль этой страницы.
В чём проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: catchAll случаем не назначено в конфиге? Можете приложить репозиторий с кодом для воспроизведения проблемы, пожалуйста?